# Can you collapse/re-arrange a table in CSS

Tags: css

Making a responsive site that contains some tables that has horizontal data that I wish to collapse or stack when we go to smaller screens.

Can table structure by styled in CSS?

I would like these to stack on top of each other, like building blocks

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="1"     style="width:100%;margin-left: 3px;">
   <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="/link31"><img src="/link1.jpg"/> style="border-style:solid; border-width:10px; float:left; max-height:236px; width:93%;" </a></td>
        <td><a href="/link2"><img src="link2.jpg"/> style="border-style:solid; border-width:10px; float:left; max-height:236px; width:93%;"</a></td>
        <td><a href="/link3"><img src="/link3.jpg"/> style="border-style:solid; border-width:10px; float:left; max-height:236px; width:92.5%;" </a></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: It is expected that you at least attempt to code this for yourself. Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. I would suggest that you do some additional research, either via Google or by searching SO, make an attempt and. if you still have trouble, come back with **your code** and explain what you have tried and why it did not work.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Also, please close your `<img>` tags like `<img src="..." />`

Answer (score 1):

Use media queries.It is used to make a web-page responsive.
I am giving a very simple example you can write according to you.

```
    @media only screen and (min-width : 320px) and (max-width : 480px) {

        td[class="img-header"]{

            width:100% !important;
            display:block;
        }

    }
    @media only screen and (min-width : 480px) and (max-width : 767px) {

        td[class="img-header"]{

            width:100% !important;
            display:block;


        }

    }
   @media only screen and (min-width : 768px) and (max-width :1200px) {
     //your css code
  }
```

JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Dee0565/q5Ldq3ny/

Answer (score 1):

I take it you're looking for a quick, responsive solution to this. If JQuery is an option for you, there's a plugin called StackTable that will take care of this for you. Here's a link to the demo: http://johnpolacek.github.io/stacktable.js/

Answer (score 0):

You absolutely can do this -- just declare the elements you want to stack as `display:block;`

See this very simple example:
http://jsfiddle.net/cn858387/